# write css property pbackground in js ,cant work in firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

this js funciton:

```
function(strIDHead) {
    var leftTD = document.getElementById(strIDHead + "_left");
    if (leftTD != null) {
        leftTD.background = "Images/Button/button_left.gif";
    }
}
```

can only work in ie,i want it work in firefox,how to do it?
ps:i tried

```
if (leftTD != null) leftTD.background = "url(/Images/Button/button_left.gif)";
```

cant work either...

Comment: Hungarian Notation is horrible.

Comment: i think in js using Hungarian Notation  is better... but I dont know why i think so

Comment: PS:my manger said it must use pure javascript...

Comment: It certainly isn't better. For example, passing an integer to that function would not cause any problems.

Comment: but javascript didn't require strong type check ,in your js variable  telling caller what type should pass better than knowing nothing at all.if the caller pass in a int to a str prefix variable ,I have no words...

Comment: That's what comments are meant for. You could even use javadoc-style comments.

Comment: @SleeplessKnight let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2839/discussion-between-thiefmaster-and-sleeplessknight)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (leftTD) leftTD.style.background = "url(Images/Button/button_left.gif)";
```

Or if you can use jQuery (whole function, not just the last line):

```
$('#' + strIDHead + '_list').css('background', 'url(Images/Button/button_left.gif)');
```

Update: Your function header is incorerct, too, unless you want an anonymous function and just forgot to copy the code where it's assigned somewhere. The correct function would looke like this:

```
function someFunction(strIDHead) {
    var leftTD = document.getElementById(strIDHead + "_left");
    if (leftTD) {
        leftTD.style.background = "url(Images/Button/button_left.gif)";
    }
}
```

Comment: That might mean he's stupid.. at least if you do more complex things. Anyway, the first line doesn't need anything and should work. If not try with `backgroundImage` instead of `background`.

Comment: that was a little harsh :) @SleeplessKnight: maintaining code cross browser is a little difficult.

Comment: @SleeplessKnight — jQuery **is** pure JS. (Setting a graphical background, however, requires HTML and CSS to be involved, as well as the image itself).

Comment: leftTD.style.background = "url(Images/Button/button_left.gif)";  this worked,thanks! 兼容性伤不起！！！